# Space between tables in Birt for PDF

Tags: reporting-services, birt

I have 1 table and according to the database(group header), the table multiplies itself, usually it is only 1 and sometimes 2, 2 tables fit in 1 page but now I have a rare situation; 4 tables. After the headline all blank, next page 3 tables, following page 1 table. I would like to leave some space after each table so they don't have to be sticked to each other and can be separated like : Headline + 2 tables and then next page 2 tables. I inserted a group footer, this inserted a new line between the tables but still not enough, I need maybe like 3-4 lines to accomplish this. Any tips are welcome.

Comment: Also posted http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/31161-space-between-tables-in-birt-for-pdf/

Comment: @JamesJenkins yes because different forums are watched by different coders/developers if Vlad was not on actuate forum, I could maybe never solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table rows have margins. You can increase, for instance, a bottom margin of the header row or the top margin of the first details row.

To the question, why there three tables were shifted to the next page, though there was some free space on the first page. Check "Page Break" properties of your tables, groups and rows. Especially "Page Break / Inside = Avoid" will make complete row or table being shifted to the next page if the current page doesn't have enough space for the entire content of the row or table.

Comment: Thank you very much, Switching from Avoid to Auto solved my problem! Thanks again!